# For some older pdfs the `includepdf` command displays empty pages

Tags: pdf, bugs, emptypage

I have a XeTeX code as below, but for this [n16.pdf](https://smallpdf.com/result#r=feff2e075406077e4804a0b9b40884f4&t=share-document) it renders empty pages.
This is true for most of pre-2000 year pdfs I have.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor


\usepackage[footwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{plain}




\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}

\robustify{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page} \ \roman{page}\ \texthebrew{\hebrewnumeral{\value{page}}}}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\thepage{\texthebrew{\protect\hebrewnumeral{1}}}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Hebrew something}

 

\begin{document}

 

     
      \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 0.0cm 5.0cm]{n16.pdf}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem a few weeks back. It turned out that the encoding of the PDF file wasn't correct. Using a PDF Editor (I used the commercial PDFEditor) I could open the files and save them again. After that I could add the PDF files to my TeX document again. Maybe this works in your case too.

Comment: if you compile with `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv"`  I get the warnings `xdvipdfmx:warning: DecodeFilter "LZWDecode" not supported.`. You could try to include the pdf first with pdflatex in a new pdf, and then to include the result with xelatex. Or to resave them with ghostscript.

Comment: @alchemist Your advice is funny but works well.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please, what is this: `"xdvipdfmx -vv"` ?

Comment: the -vv option activates more messages from xdvipdfmx